# Closing a repeated task once and for all doesn't work

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

According to the [docs](http://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html), `C-- 1 C-c C-t` aka `org-todo` with a negative prefix should close a repeated task once and for all. Unfortunately it just doesn't work for me. Any ideas what could be causing this or how I could close the task?

Alternatives seem to be to manually set the task to `DONE`, delete it, archive it, ... However, I would like to get my setup working :)

EDIT: By "it just doesn't work" I meant that the task is logged as done with the current time but is also rescheduled immediately, i.e. it's not fully closeable.

Comment: What does it do? I did not know this until now - but to me it works as you described and changes the state to `DONE`. Can you post the error msg if any?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no error message. Interestingly enough, if the item doesn't have a `TODO` state but e.g. `ON HOLD` instead, then the status gets updated to `TODO`. But it never goes to `DONE`. That's why I figure that there might something wrong with my org-mode setup, but I'm not sure which of the myriad config variables would be the right one to look at :)

Comment: Could you try to find function `org-cancel-repeat` (for example, with `C-h C-f`)?  I found that this function appears in release 8.2.3b (in 2013), but in my version 8.2.10 this function doesn't exist and `org-todo` does nothing with this `-1` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was surprised to find that the officially documented solution _now_ works as well. Can't recall the version of Emacs I was working with when I wrote the original post.